# Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-workbench

Para un conteo de visitantes intento usar Mysql y php, intento conectar el segundo con el primero de la forma que dice la documentación, de esta manera:

```
<?php 
$start = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","contraseña","counter");
?>
```

Pero me sale este mensaje:
"Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in D:\Program Files (x86)\Xampp\htdocs\aqw\d.php:2 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in D:\Program Files (x86)\Xampp\htdocs\aqw\d.php on line 2"

Ya fui a php.ini e intenté descomentar la linea extension=mysqli, pero ya estaba descomentada, usé phpinfo(), y lo que veo es que tengo una seccion que se llama mysqlnl, pero por ningun lado mysqli. Mi sospecha es que quizá tendrá que ver con que uso php de xampp pero no uso el sql del mismo porque no usa mysql sino mariadb, asi que me descarge mysql y workbench desde oracle.

Edit: adjunto todas la lineas en php.ini donde aparece la palabra mysqli:

```
extension=mysqli
mysqli.max_persistent=-1
;mysqli.allow_local_infile = On
mysqli.allow_persistent=On
mysqli.max_links=-1
mysqli.default_port=3306
mysqli.default_socket=
mysqli.default_host=
mysqli.default_user=
mysqli.default_pw=
mysqli.reconnect=Off
```

Solo la tercera tenia punto y coma.

Comment: Mysqli es una función de PHP así que no aplicaría lo último que mencionas

Comment: Haz una búsqueda del término *`mysqli`* en tu `php.ini`, recopila todo lo que encuentres (la línea completa) y agrégalo a la pregunta pulsando en [edit].

Comment: @A.Cedano       listo, añadi lo que solicitaste.

Comment: Pon la extensión así: `extension=php_mysqli.dll` Guarda el archivo ini y reinicia el servidor y prueba si funciona.

Comment: @A.Cedano no funcionó, lo copie y pegué tal cual y reinicié mi pc, y nada.

Comment: Debe ser sin duda un problema de configuración. Lamentablemente no tengo ninguna experiencia con el uso de Xampp y hace más de 10 años que no toco un equipo Windows. Mira si [lo intentando por este usuario aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43848269/php-7-1-x-mysqli-connect-isnt-defined-extension-is-turned-on) puede ayudarte a encontrar el problema, supongo que Xampp tendrá formas de saber los drivers que tienes instalados, las rutas de las instalaciones y demás. Supongo que tendrá también un log de errores o alguna forma de saber los módulos que dan error cuando intentas cargarlos.

Comment: Debes abrir el archivo `php.ini` correspondiente a la versión activa de PHP. Revisa las instrucciones específicas para [XAMPP](https://anthoncode.com/activar-extensiones-de-en-xampp/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya resolví el problema, era una mala configuración de Mysql, al principio estaba como desarrollador, pero lo reinstalé como servidor, después reinstalé el Xampp con su Mysql deshabilitado y funcionó.

[image: Ventana de instalación]

Comment: Ok ya queda más claro 

Answer (score 0):

según el manual de php

https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mysqli-connect.php

dice que la función que mencionas  mysqli-connect usada para la conexión a base de datos es usada en versiones 5 o superiores

usa dentro de un archivo PHP la siguiente función y ábrelo

```
<?php

    phpinfo();

?>
```

para mostrar tu version, si esta por debajo de la requerida actualízala.

Coloco esto como respuesta ya que no indicas que versión usas.

Comment: Buen punto aunque sería algo raro, ya que la versión 5.x todas están descontinuadas https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php

Comment: Es version 8.0.1

Comment: has intentado hacer la conexion usando el metodo pdo? 

https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.connections.php

Comment: Sí lo intenté, pero me dice que no encuentra el driver, sin embargo sí encontré su extension en el php.ini, no se si con driver se referirá a eso.